# Why is the default value of the connection property `allowLoadLocalInfile` has been changed to false

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

Why is the default value of the connection property `allowLoadLocalInfile` has been changed to `fasle` in Mysql connector/j 5.1.49. This [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-5.1-relnotes-en/news-5-1-49.html) suggests that this change is made for these bugs (Bug #29261254, Bug #30866178), but how can I know what these bugs are, where to check these bugs?

Comment: If you have a support contract with Oracle then you can look them up in My Oracle Support at https://support.oracle.com/ - but only if they are published bugs; a lot are kept hidden, including those two it seems.

Comment: do I need to pay for their support? @AlexPoole